# Getting sql query results in Codeignitor and display on web page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using a CMS system called CSZCMS which is build on Codeignitor 3.10. I have built a form to collect user data from a survey, which loads data to a MySQL Table. Using PHPadmin I have created a query to get the results I need. What I can't find how to do though is display the results from the query on a web page in the CMS. I think it is missing the connection string to the db as CMS is using CodeIgnitor framework.

Created Form, loaded data to db, created SQL, used PHPAdmin to create the PHP script below. Inserted below php code into web page.

$query = mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT `Channel`, `Which Company`, `Offer`, `Business Sector`, `url Link`, `Discount Code`, `Contact`, `Sector`FROM `form_deal_form` WHERE 1");

I expected to see the data from the table on the web page and every time web page loads it gets latest data from db table.

Comment: you have to code all your queries in models. then get them(which method you want) in your controller. after that pass them to the view as array.

if you don't know what is MVC so ask someone else to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->db->query()` instead of

mysqli_query()

```
$query= "SELECT Channel, Which Company, Offer, Business Sector, url Link, Discount Code, Contact, SectorFROM form_deal_form WHERE 1";

$data= $this->db->query($query);
```

This will get ur result in data

For more details about this refer codeigniter documentation

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Better to use codeignitor query builder

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Good answer by Shafeeque TP, even better is to use the query builder or active record class provided by codeigniter. To do that, go to your `application/config/autoload.php`, go to `$autoload['libraries']` and add `'database'` to the array, that way you don't have to manually load it.

For the query part, simply do this:

```
$this->db->select('Channel', 'Which Company', 'Offer', 'Business Sector', 'url Link', 'Discount Code', 'Contact', 'Sector')
         ->from('form_deal_form')
         ->where(1)
         ->get()
         ->result();
```

Not sure the `WHERE` part of your query is correct, I just put a `1` for the sake of converting your query to the active record class. As a side note you don't have to use `result();` to generate your query results, that was just an example. You can find more ways to generate results in the links provided by Shafeeque TP.